System.CalloutException: Illegal character in opaque part
I've got a problem calling the below endpoint from apex. I created named credentials and auth provider to authenticate with the service and while executing the http request, I'm getting below error Any help would be appreciated!
endpoint: request.setEndpoint('callout:TEST_API/V1.0/users?$fetch="userId:123456"');
System.CalloutException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 35: callout:TEST_API/V1.0/users?$fetch="userId:123456"

@DavidCheng Wrong Q&A. We figured it out.

This error is complaining about the literal " in the URL. Make sure you're using EncodingUtil.urlEncode to encode parameters that are not permitted in the URL schema.

Thanks! that did the trick!
